# sum until a value is reached

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I want to take user inputs from 3 values(Let's say 2, 5, 10) and add them until a particular value is reached (Example 100) and stop the process. I'm having trouble choosing whether the for loop is to be used or if-else statements or while break statements.

Comment: 2 + 5 +10 is 17 this has not reached 100, you want to add them again and again?

Comment: yeah to keep taking values until it reaches 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want this:

```py
def special_sum(values=[2, 5, 10], maximum=100):
    result = 0

    for value in in values:
        if result > maximum:
            break
        result += value

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add them over and over again until its greater than or equal to 100 then you can do this -

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
c = int(input("Enter the third number: "))

sum = a+b+c

while(True):
    if (sum+sum)>=100:
        break
    
    sum = sum+sum
    print(sum)
```

Comment: But each input needs to be defined individually for that.

Comment: Thanks to point out